# I have ViewPager related issue in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have one **ScrollView** and it contain one **ViewPager** and one **RecyclerView** and i have applied timer to auto scroll viewpager content and I want is when I click on view pager it holds down it don't want to perform auto scroll task and for that I used below code.

```
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              canScroll = false;
              Log.e("canScroll", "ACTION_DOWN = " + canScroll);
          }

          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              canScroll = true;
              Log.e("canScroll", "ACTION_UP = " + canScroll);
          }

          return true;
       }
    });

    public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); // delay
    }

    // this is an inner class...
    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("canScroll", "RemindTask = " + canScroll);
                        if (canScroll) {
                            if (currentPage < maxPage) {
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
                                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                            } else {
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
                                currentPage = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Unwanted", "RemindTask- NullPointerException");
            }
        }
    }
```

And I want is when I scroll viewpager horizontally it want to scroll but it is not working **and also** when I click on viewpager and then scroll it vertically the ScrollView is scrolled vertically but then I can not able to detect **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** and due to that I can not able to set ***canScroll = true*** to perform autoscroll viewpager content And this layout is in ***Fragment***.

So please someone help me out.

[image]

Comment: try nested scrollView

Comment: My actual problem with view pager.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
public void pageSwitcher() {
        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("canScroll", "RemindTask = " + canScroll);
                        if (canScroll) {
                            if (currentPage < maxPage) {
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
                                currentPage++;
                            } else {
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
                                currentPage = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
```

onTouch listener is same as your's

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    canScroll = false;
                    Log.e("canScroll", "ACTION_DOWN = " + canScroll);
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    canScroll = true;
                    Log.e("canScroll", "ACTION_UP = " + canScroll);
                }

                return true;

            }


        });
```

tested in Redmi device
comment if any Query

Comment: Its not that one that i have required.